# Add Sergei Strelec's WinPE to existing Usb boot UEFI for W10 setup

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, bootable-media

It is possible to have on the same Usb UEFI,Windows 10 setup and other bootable like [Sergei Strelec's WinPE](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/Sergei-Strelec-s-WinPE.shtml)?
thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hi,I've edit my post.thanks

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but you may try  https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html   You might need to disable Secure Boot though. It will be ISOs files stored therein, not extracted Setup(s) and bootloader will pick the selected ISO and start the boot/installation etc from the boot menu interface.

Comment: Indeed,Ventoy is a good solution:you can boot from iso placed directly on the usb(secure boot must be disabled,it can be reactivated later)